# AJAX File Upload to PHP after AJAX Complete - Missing Link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

It is a Wordpress installation using Gravity Forms which I know pretty well, however what I am trying to do is get the value of a hidden input and use it in a PHP script to get more data about.

JS CODE: http://pastebin.com/5FFf4ESb

```
jQuery(function($){

$(document).bind('gform_post_render', function(event, form_id){

    if (form_id == 1) {


        var uploader = $("#gform_drag_drop_area_1_1");

    var uploads = $("#gform_uploaded_files_1").val();

     alert(uploads);

    uploader.on("drop", function() {  

    $.ajax({
    url: mp3_object.ajaxurl,
    async: true,
    type: "POST",
    data: {
    action : 'ajax_mp3',
    files : uploads, 
    },

    success: function(response) {
        //results = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        alert(response);
    }
});

});




        }



    });



});
```

PHP CODE: http://pastebin.com/H2Cd1Dfd

```
function enqueue_mp3_scripts_init($form, $is_ajax) {
     if ( $is_ajax ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mp3-script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), 1.0 ); // jQuery will be included automatically
    wp_localize_script( 'mp3-script', 'mp3_object', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) ); // setting ajaxurl
     }
    }

add_action('gform_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_mp3_scripts_init', 10, 2);

function ajax_mp3_func() {


    if( isset($_POST['files']) )  {

    echo $_POST['files'];               
    }

die(); // stop executing script
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_mp3', 'ajax_mp3_func' ); // ajax for logged in users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_mp3', 'ajax_mp3_func' ); // ajax for not logged in users
```

The issue I am having is that the file upload uses plupload AJAX request and it is performing asynchronously with my JS code so my code fires before the value of the hidden field var uploads is set and it returns empty before being sent via my AJAX request to the PHP File.

I don't know enough about AJAX to know how to isolate and run my AJAX request after the hidden value is set.

Comment: You could just mark the async:true to false, this will make the request syncronous.

Comment: I've tried that as well.  Unfortunately that doesn't work.  It fires the request before the file is even dropped.  These functions are in different script files or I would certainly run my AJAX call in the success function of the upload script

Comment: Have you tried **when()** jQuery method?

Comment: @m.antkowicz - I must admit I wasn't even aware of the existence of when().  I am not sure how I would implement it in this situation as the documentation indicates that when expects one or more deferred objects and I don't know much about the plupload object

Comment: On the **when** referencje page there is example with **$.ajax** please notice it. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when If it won't work for you second solution can be using **$(dokument).ajaxstop()**